# opencv stitching code showing error when ported with ndk in eclipse for android App

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk, opencv-stitching

I am trying to build an application for stitching on phone using `OpenCV`.
I am able to compile c++ code using ndk .The `OpenCV` stitching_detailed sample when I am using as native code in eclipse it is showing errors (mostly variable not resolved) and some of the structs in the library ,though they are registered with eclipse(as it is showing by cursor hovering) when i am accessing their member elements it is showing non resolved variables.
The exact same code is running good  through command line without NDK but I am not able to port it with NDK.

Someone help me here.

Answer (score 0):

In `Project/Properties/ > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols` see that you add all the include files pertaining to OpenCV.

And when you're including files like `#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>` etc., give the whole path of the h/hpp file(s).

This will resolve.